# Linear force vs. displacement relationship for crystalline solid

Tags: forces, condensed-matter, crystals, phonons, density-functional-theory

I did a series of density functional theory (DFT) calculations on crystalline silicon.

These consisted of 50 total displacements of one atom from equilibrium in the x-direction until the displacement was 0.5 angstroms (increments of 0.01 angstroms).

A 0.5 angstrom displacement is large for this material. To give some perspective, the average atomic displacement above room temperature is around 0.3 angstroms.

I therefore expected the force vs. displacement relation to be nonlinear due to anharmonic effects.

But the forces on the displaced atom and every other atom exhibits PURELY linear behavior! No deviation whatsoever from a straight line up to a 0.5 angstrom for one atom.

Why is it a linear relationship? Surely anharmonic effects must come in at this magnitude of a displacement?

This was so mind boggling to me...

Comment: Could you provide a few more details? E.g. on the software and particular potentials that were used?

Comment: I used VASP with GGA (PBE) pseudopotentials, considering 4 valence electrons. I used a 6x6x6 k-point grid on a 64 atom cluser (2x2x2 unit cell) of silicon.

Comment: 3 years is long for no answer, why not copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com?